# Orbeon 2018.1 TinyMCE broken/different

Tags: tinymce, orbeon, xforms

I've got Orbeon 2017.2.2 and Orbeon 2018.1 side-by-side for testing purposes. Forms are loaded from eXist-db 4.3.1. Code for the text editor is like this:

```
<xforms:textarea mediatype="text/html" ref="." incremental="true">
    <xforms:label ref="$resources/description" class="hidden"/>
</xforms:textarea>
```

Note that this code did not change from Orbeon 3.9, where we did not use TinyMCE just yet.

In Orbeon 2017.2.2 (see screenshot, left hand side) everything appears to be fine. In Orbeon 2018.1 (see screenshot, right hand side), the buttons are still functional, but the TineMCE woff/svg/ttf files are missing and so they do not render properly.

What am I missing in Orbeon 2018.1 for TinyMCE?

[image: Before page-flow update Orbeon 2017.2.2 left, Orbeon 2018.1 right]

Update: I'm one step closer. We have our own page-flow.xml. After adding woff|svg|ttf to the controller/files line, I can almost now see the same thing in the 2017 and 2018 editions of Orbeon. The 2017 edition still looks a whole lot smoother by default though. I'm not sure the whole lightgray TinyMCE theme is loaded in 2018.

[image: After page-flow update Orbeon 2017.2.2 left, Orbeon 2018.1 right]

Answer (score 2):

As documented in the Orbeon 2018.1 release notes, Orbeon 2017.2.2 was the last version to be shipped with TinyMCE 3. Not so obvious was that it also was the last version to be shipped with thebigreason skin. The default lightgray skin is indeed as ugly as the author of thebigreason skin led to believe. While Orbeon 2018.1 comes with all the plugins you need, it doesn't come with other languages or skins. After installing/creating those you may call them using a custom initialization as described in the [Orbeon documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/rich-text-editor).

This is mine, for now:

```
<xhtml:script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var TINYMCE_CUSTOM_CONFIG = {
        language:                   "en",
        skin:                       "lightgray",
        menu:                       {},
        plugins:                    "spellchecker table save paste lists link visualchars nonbreaking template fullscreen",
        toolbar:                    "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | removeformat | link unlink | fullscreen",
        doctype:                    '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">',
        encoding:                   "xml",
        entity_encoding:            "raw",
        forced_root_block:          'div',
        remove_redundant_brs:       true,
        verify_html:                true,
        branding:                   false,
        editor_css:                 "",      // don't let the editor load UI CSS because that fails in portlets
        content_style:              "* {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;}",
        height:                     300,
        max_height:                 500,
        resize:                     true
    };
]]></xhtml:script>
```

Comment: I suppose that ugliness is subjective. The "lightgray" skin is fairly basic for sure, although I am not sure I like the older skin either ;)